# My angularJS timer wont work for ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
      function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.counter = 5;
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){
        $scope.counter--;
        if ($scope.counter > 0) {
            mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
        }
        else {
            alert("Time is up!");
        }
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

    $scope.reset= function(){
        $scope.counter = 5;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
    }

}
  }); 
}​​
```

This is my js code and my html is below

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc11.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
{{counter}}
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why this wont work. it keeps just displaying the timer as {{countdown}} and not updating it to run the JS, I have JS enabled with Chrome and it just wont run.

Comment: `angular-1.0.0rc11`? Seriously? The stable version is 1.3.15. Your html doesn't have any script for ionic, so how could the application start? Open your chrome console: you'll have errors listed there. Never close it while developing.

Comment: This is just a test trying to get the timer to start on a blank page, I was going to worry about Ionic later, this is not being ran with ionic serve yet

Comment: But the fact is that your module depends on the ionic module, and use the $ionicPlatform service. How could that work if ionic is not available?

Comment: I guess I cant do it my way then. I was going to make it as a standard webpage first then Ionic afterwards. Is that not possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. But then don't use anything from ionic in your standard web page.

Comment: I think you would need to pass $timeout into the run function. `.run(function($ionicPlatform, $timeout) {});` Otherwise you would probably get a $timeout is undefined error.